# Selecting the n'th range/island of rows where columns have a common value?

Tags: sqlite

I need to select all rows (for a range) which have a common value within a column.

For example (starting from the last row)

I try to select all of the rows where `_user_id == 1` until `_user_id != 1` ?

In this case resulting in selecting rows [4, 5, 6]

```
+------------------------+
| _id  _user_id   amount |
+------------------------+
| 1    1          777    |
| 2    2          1      |
| 3    2          11     |
| 4    1          10     |
| 5    1          100    |
| 6    1          101    |
+------------------------+

/*Create the table*/
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 ( 
_id              INTEGER           PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
_user_id         INTEGER,
amount           INTEGER);

/*Add the datas*/
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1, 1, 777);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(2, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(3, 2, 11);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(4, 1, 10);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(5, 1, 100);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(6, 1, 101);

/*Check the datas*/
SELECT * FROM t1;

1|1|777
2|2|1
3|2|11
4|1|10
5|1|100
6|1|101
```

In my attempt I use [Common Table Expressions](https://blog.expensify.com/2015/09/25/the-simplest-sqlite-common-table-expression-tutorial/) to group the results of `_user_id`. This gives the index of the last row containing a unique value (eg. `SELECT _id FROM t1 GROUP BY _user_id LIMIT 2;` will produce: [6, 3])

I then use those two values to select a range where `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1` is the lower end (3) and `LIMIT 1` is the upper end (6)

```
WITH test AS (
    SELECT _id FROM t1 GROUP BY _user_id LIMIT 2
) SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE _id BETWEEN 1+ (
    SELECT * FROM test LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
) and (
    SELECT * FROM test LIMIT 1
);
```

Output:

```
4|1|10
5|1|100
6|1|101
```

This appears to work ok at selecting the last "island" but what I really need is a way to select the n'th island.

Is there a way to generate a query capable of producing outputs like these when provided a parameter `n`?:

```
island (n=1): 
   4|1|10
   5|1|100
   6|1|101

island (n=2): 
   2|2|1
   3|2|11

island (n=3): 
   1|1|777
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables are unordered, so the only way to search for islands is to search for consecutive `_id` values:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t1_with_islands(_id, _user_id, amount, island_number) AS (
  SELECT _id,
         _user_id,
         amount,
         1
  FROM t1
  WHERE _id = (SELECT max(_id)
               FROM t1)

  UNION ALL

  SELECT t1._id,
         t1._user_id,
         t1.amount,
         CASE WHEN t1._user_id = t1_with_islands._user_id
              THEN island_number
              ELSE island_number + 1
         END
  FROM t1
  JOIN t1_with_islands ON t1._id = (SELECT max(_id)
                                    FROM t1
                                    WHERE _id < t1_with_islands._id)
)
SELECT *
FROM t1_with_islands
ORDER BY _id;
```

Comment: Thank you for supplying this! I am however having some trouble where if I delete a row then it will stop at the prior row due to the primary keys no longer being consecutive. Any thoughts?

Comment: ⁎grumble⁎ that is not what the original question asked for …

Comment: Very sorry for not mentioning that earlier. Regardless I have found a way around it by better managing how I delete entries and ensuring that the PKs remain consecutive (though it could still be an issue in the future). But thank you very much for your answer, it was very helpful!

Comment: Changing PKs usually is a worse idea.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer too. It works amazingly well! And yes I agree about changing PKs (I'm ripping that code out now).